# Is there a way to tell if the value of a DependencyProperty came from binding source or target?

Tags: wpf, binding, dependency-properties

I sometimes want to know if the value of a dependency property came from user input or from a change in the binding source.
I have yet not found a clean way to determine this.

There are stuff like [DependencyPropertyHelper](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencypropertyhelper(v=vs.110).aspx) but it does not help with this scenario as far as I can tell.

The scenario: `<TextBox Text="{Binding Foo}" />`

Find out if it was the binding source or target that updated `Text` last.
Or something else, yes I'm aware of triggers, inheritance animations etc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get the binding expression associated with a Dependency Property and check its status:

```
BindingOperations.GetBindingExpressionBase(textBox, TextBox.TextProperty)?.Status == 
    BindingStatus.Active
```

You can combine it with `DependencyPropertyHelper` to check if the current source is `BaseValueSource.Local`.

`ValueSource` also has a property called `IsExpression` that is set to `true` when using a binding or any other expression, such as `DynamicResource` or `TemplateBinding`.

Finding whether the current value came from the source or the target is harder. AFAIK there's no better way than this:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Foo, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}"
         SourceUpdated="OnSourceUpdated" TargetUpdated="OnTargetUpdated" />
```

Then you can hookup the handlers `OnSourceUpdated` and `OnTargetUpdated` and apply some logic. You can also created an attached property and update it for better encapsulation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, gonna need to experiment with this and see if it works.

Comment: It shows `Status: Active, BaseValueSource: Local` for both when the value came from source and target when I test it.

Comment: Have an upvote, unfortunately I can't use `NotifyOnSourceUpdated` and `NotifyOnTargetUpdated` as I have no control of how the bindings are created.

Comment: I have an idea about cloning the binding and binding to a proxy property. Cloning will be a huge mess.

Comment: Yeah I discourage myself from it, hence asking this question. This is inside a control btw.